# Use output of method as final variable

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Scenario:**

There is a method which generates a Password for Students. All Students must use this password. We need to verify that all Student types can access the test papers with this password.

```
testClass extends BaseClass{
testStudent1(){
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathExpression)).sendKeys(login.generatePassword());
}

testStudent2(){
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathExpression)).sendKeys(login.generatePassword());
}

}
```

Problem is both these Student methods are getting a new password. How can I generate a password once and use it all across the project? Something like class variable.

Excuse me for such novice question.

Comment: what's the code of `login.generatePassword()`? Why don't you just call generatePassword once only then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a static field

```
testClass extends BaseClass{
private static String pw = null;

testStudent1(){

   if (pw == null) 
          pw = login.generatePassword();

   driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathExpression)).sendKeys(pw);

}
```

You may have to consider Thread-safety if using in a multi-threaded environment

Comment: You have an error in your logic. `sendKeys` is `void`. It won't return password to `pw` variable

Comment: @RafałLaskowski Thanks,  I just noticed that I was not consider how he was intending to use the solution - have fixed.

Comment: Looks great now. I think OP have a variety of solutions :)

Comment: This is what I am looking for, thanks. Could you please change the title of the question. I don't what do we call it in Java world.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of solutions.

Given the example above, I would add a `public static final String` to your `BaseClass`.

```
class BaseClass {
    public static final String studentPassword = new Login().generatePassword();
}
```

In this case, your tests would look like this:

```
testClass extends BaseClass{
testStudent1(){
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathExpression)).sendKeys(studentPassword);
}

testStudent2(){
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathExpression)).sendKeys(studentPassword);
}

}
```

I would also make `generatePassword()` a `static` method.

Comment: This is a better version

Answer (score 0):

You can use static variable to store the password generated only once,

You can do,

```
public static String pswd = login.generatePassword();
```

and use this `pswd` as function parameter.